# Applescript makes file that cannot be edited

Tags: applescript, file-permissions, textedit

This code creates a new html file in the open folder and then tells textedit to open it for editing.

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell application "Finder" to set currentDir to (target of front Finder window) as text
    make new file at currentDir with properties {name:"test.html"}

    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        open ("test.html")
    end tell
end tell
```

Trouble is Textedit complains with:

The document “test.html” could not be opened. You don’t have permission.

What is the problem with TextEdit?

Answer (score 0):

The open command needs a file object or a path to a file:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set currentDir to (target of front Finder window) as text
    set htmlfile to make new file at currentDir with properties {name:"test.html"}
end tell

tell application "TextEdit" to open htmlfile
#This will probably open the HTML file in your default browser.

#Try this to open the file with TextEdit
do shell script "open -a textedit " & quoted form of POSIX path of (htmlfile as text)
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help but now i get a dialog that says:  'Are you sure you want to modify the document in place?'   `Modifying the document in place might cause you to lose some of the original formatting.  Would you like to duplicate the document first?'

Comment: turns out this is a text edit problem. I will post a new question.